# UICollectionViewCell not displaying properly after reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a frustrating issue with UICollectionViewCells.  I am using the default flow in this app.  Here is the issue:

When initially loaded, the "Closed" label displays properly across the cells.  We the CollectionView is reloaded by either pulling down or by going to another page and returning, the "Closed" label only displays on the first cell.

The "Closed" label was added in IB and is named.  I tried using the label name as well as tagging the label and using the tag reference.

When I debug the code it goes through the correct flow for the "Closed" label.  the "Closed" label is instanced and is not nil.  It appears in code that everything should be happy and good, but displayed it is not.

Here is a screenshot of the initial load of the data:

[image: Initial Load - Displayed Correctly]

Here is the screenshot of the reload:

[image: Reload - Displayed Incorrectly]

And now for the code - here is the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function:

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableString *topMiddle = [NSMutableString new];
    NSMutableString *bottomMiddle = [NSMutableString new];
    NSMutableString *bottom = [NSMutableString new];

    Tab *theTab = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // figure out the date this started
    [bottomMiddle appendString:@"Start: "];
    [bottomMiddle appendString:[_dateFormatted stringFromDate:[theTab startdate]]];

    // figure out the due date/closed date stuff
    if ([theTab closeddate] != nil) {
        [bottom appendString:@"Closed: "];
        [bottom appendString:[_dateFormatted stringFromDate:[theTab closeddate]]];
    } else if ([theTab duedate] == nil) {
        [bottom appendString:@"No Due Date"];

    } else if ([theTab duedate] != nil){
        [bottom appendString:@"Due: "];
        [bottom appendString:[_dateFormatted stringFromDate:[theTab duedate]]];
    }

    long duedaterange = [self numberOfDaysTillDueDate:[theTab duedate]];

    CreditorCollectionViewCell *cellC;
    if ([[theTab debitor] intValue] == 0) {
        cellC = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseCreditorIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cellC.topLabel setText:[theTab name]];

        [topMiddle appendString:@"They Owe: "];
        [topMiddle appendString:@"\n"];
        [topMiddle appendString:[_currencyFormatted stringFromNumber:[theTab amountcurrent]]];
        [cellC.topMiddleLabel setText:topMiddle];

        [cellC.bottomMiddleLabel setText:bottomMiddle];

        [cellC.bottomLabel setText:bottom];

        [cellC setTheTab:theTab];

        // set this as hidden unless it is closed
        if ([theTab closeddate] == nil) {
            [[cellC viewWithTag:102] setHidden:YES];
        } else {
            [[cellC viewWithTag:102] setHidden:NO];
        }

        if ([theTab closeddate] != nil) {
            // the tab is CLOSED
            [cellC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

            [[cellC viewWithTag:102] setCenter:cellC.center];
            [[cellC viewWithTag:102] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [(UILabel *)[cellC viewWithTag:102] setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

            CGAffineTransform tcheck = [cellC viewWithTag:102].transform;

            // make sure the transform has not been applied already
            if ((tcheck.a == 0 || tcheck.a == 1) && (tcheck.b == 0 || tcheck.b == 1) &&
                (tcheck.c == 0 || tcheck.c == 1) && (tcheck.d == 0 || tcheck.d == 1)) {

                // turn the closed sign
                float angleDim = (cellC.bounds.size.height/cellC.bounds.size.width);
                float angle = atanf(angleDim);

                // apply the trnasformation to angle the closed label
                CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([cellC viewWithTag:102].transform, -angle);
                [cellC viewWithTag:102].transform = transform;
            }

        } else if ((duedaterange == 0) && ([bottom containsString:@"No Due Date"])) {
            // either day of or none set
            [cellC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        } else if (duedaterange >= 10) {
            // more than 10 days out (green)
            [cellC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        } else if (duedaterange < 0) {
            // PAST DUE (red)
            [cellC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } else {
            // coming close (yellow)
            [cellC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        }

        return cellC;

    }

    return nil;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only have one view with tag 102, or if you can have more than one, your code is only acting on one. Try going back to using an IBOutlet for the label and refer to it by name.

Comment: It acts the same if I use an IBOutlet rather than the tag value

Comment: You are passing a reference to theTab to the cell. Does the cell have any show/hide logic based on theTab? What does the code for the cell look like?

Comment: The cell only has the tab object and the references to the custom label. There is no logic in the cell itself for the display of the closed label -- and the lightbulb just went on. I will move the closed label logic to the cell itself

Comment: I tried moving the show logic for the Closed label in the custom cell itself but it did not work so I removed the logic.  There is no logic in the custom cell.